# variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a class like this

```
class aClass
{
  public:
    aClass() : N(5) {}
    void aMemberFunction()
    {
      int nums[N] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
  private:
    const int N;
};
```

The testing code is

```
int main()
{
  aClass A;
  A.aMemberFunction();

  const int N = 5;
  int ints[N] = {5,4,3,2,1};
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile (g++ 4.6.2 20111027), I get the error

```
problem.h: In member function ‘void aClass::aMemberFunction()’:
problem.h:7:31: error: variable-sized object ‘nums’ may not be initialized
```

If I comment out the line with `int nums[N]` I don't get a compilation error, so the similar code for the `ints` array is fine. Isn't the value of `N` known at compile time?

What's going on? Why is `nums` considered a variable-sized array? Why are the arrays `nums` and `ints` handled differently?

Comment: In C++ arrays require constant expressions for their size. i.e. it must be a compile-time constant, but N in your example is initialized dynamically though to a literal.

Comment: Note that `gcc` actually support variable length arrays in C++ as an extension you just [can't initialize them like that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27339171/1708801)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Isn't the value of `N` known at compile time?

No.  At the time `aMemberFunction` is compiled, the compiler does not now what `N` is, since its value is determined at run-time.  It is not smart enough to see that there is only one constructor, and assumes that the value of `N` could be different than 5.

Comment: The C++ compiler looks not smart enough to me though, many other main stream languages can support initializing an array in the ints[N] way.

Answer (score 3):

`N` isn't known at compile time in your example, but it is in this one:

```
class aClass
{
  private:
    static const int N = 5;
  public:
    aClass() {}
    void aMemberFunction()
    {
      int nums[N] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
};
```

The above code will compile, and will declare a local array of five `int`s.

Comment: Is there any way to create a variable array? I need it to hold  X number of ints, depending on what the user enters, I have no way of knowing what they will enter so it *has* to be variable.