# Code:Blocks Mingw Compiler Error: Variable-Sized Object May Not Be Initialized

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, initialization, variable-length-array

I am creating a simple terminal fantasy game using C++. I have seemed to run into an error "error: variable-sized object 'items' may not be initialized". Here is the code:

```
string useItem(int item)
{
    string items[item] = {"HP Potion","Attack Potion","Defense Potion","Revive","Paralize Cure"};
}
```

I want to be able to use this function in order to access and return an item. How can I fix this error. I am using Code::Blocks with mingw compiler.

Comment: Raw arrays size must be known at compiled time. Otherwise you should use std::vector<std::string>

Comment: `char const* items[] = ...`?

Comment: It is also helpful to note the compiler and version you are using, in this case the answer does not change much but in other questions it could make a big difference.

Comment: Aside from the technical issues that Shafik pointed out; this code doesn't seem to make any sense. I think you actually wanted to do `string items[] = { "HP Potion", ` ... `}; return items[item];` , although you should also check `item` is in range of the number of strings in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, one variable length arrays is a C99 feature and is not part of the ISO C++ but several compilers support this feature as an extension [including gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Secondly C99 says that variable length arrays can not have an initializer, from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.8` *Initialization*:

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown
>   size or an object type that is not a variable length array type.

and alternative is to use:

```
string items[] = { ... } ;
```

and array of unknown size will have its size determined by the number of elements in the initializer.

Alternatively the idiomatic C++ way to have array of variable size would be to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).